# Firebase - Revoking refresh token doesn't delete all active sessions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to sign out the account of a user in multiple devices in which it is active.

For this, in my backend, I am doing:

```
async function deleteAccount(userId) {
  // Close all the current active sessions
  await closeAllUserActiveSessions(userId);

  return auth.deleteUser(userId);
}

async function closeAllUserActiveSessions(userId) {
  await auth.revokeRefreshTokens(userId);
  const userRecord = await auth.getUser(userId);
  const timestamp = new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000;

  functions.logger.log(`Tokens revoked at: ${timestamp}`);
}
```

I supposed that, after calling `auth.revokeRefreshTokens(userId)` the account would be automatically signed out on all devices, but that's not the case.

Is it possible to sign out all sessions? What's the use of auth.revokeRefreshTokens(userId)?

I am just trying to logout my user account (from all devices) when the user changes its password or deletes it account... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is as expected: ID tokens are bearer tokens and cannot be revoked once they are minted.

If you want existing ID tokens to be rejected after [revoking the refresh token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions), you'll need to [detect the revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation) in each backend service that uses the ID tokens to establish the caller's identity.

There is no direct notification to the other clients when a user changes their password, so you'd have to send such a notification yourself.

Comment: I have thought to: 1. store the ids of the user whose refresh token has been revoked in a Firestore collection. 2. Listen to the doc in the client side, and if added, then sign out. 3. Check the revokation using security rules before each event. 4. In my callable cloud functions, before performing any action, check that the token has not been revoked using auth.verifyIdToken(userId, checkRevoked) 5. In the client side, if a call to any cloud function throws an "auth/id-token-revoked" error, then sign out.

Comment: Is there any other simple way to handle this?

Comment: Yup, those steps sound like the correct approach indeed. It unfortunately isn't simpler, because it's not possible to actually revoke a bearer token.